# Application Settings based on Configuration Using Build Events

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I have three configurations created.  "Development", "Test", "Production".
[image: Configuration Manager]

I also have a database connection string defined in my settings
[image: Settings]

Is there a way I can utilize the following screen to ensure the proper value ends up in the setting field for each configuration?
[image]

And is the same possible for a class library housing an entity model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer you three options.

1) Use $(ConfigurationName) in your pre-build passing it into a batch file or the like.

2) Use a config files with separate sections for each build configuration. VS supports this. I think this is the best option. See below.

e.g.
[image]

3) In each project configuration declare a unique compilation symbol and use that in code for conditional compilation (not recommended).

Comment: I am going to run some tests with this to see if this fits the model.  Generally I think your answer 2 is going to work.  I keep noticing threads on here that state its easy to outgrow your app.config?  Any clues about what they are talking about?  I have multiple projects

Comment: I also purchased this book.  Just a reference comment. http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Microsoft-Build-Engine-PRO-Developer/dp/0735626286